# Optimize jQuery and CSS in WordPress Website

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, plugins

I am developing a website in WordPress 4.3. In this we use more than 20 plugins. The CSS and jQueries of every plugin are loaded on every page.

My question is: how can I optimize the styles and jQueries in that way the required styles and jQueries are included on each page.

I am trying `wp_enque_script()` but cannot get success. Also I am going to do that, include CSS and jQuery on each page that they required. But I think this is not a better way.

URL of my website is: http://omtut.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use conditional logics. Ex: if you need to include "homepage.js" only on home page, you may try

```
if(is_home()){
    // use wp_enque_script() function to include the said js file
}
```

Likewise you can include only the required js/css files in each page.

Comment: But all files are loaded through `wp_head()`. So how i handle this

Comment: wp_enque_script() function is used in functions.php, so open up the functions.php file on your theme and try to optimize those js/css files there. And make sure to remove the entries including those js/css files initially. ( may be plugins or on your theme code )